# JDWP in Embedded JRE in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, jdwp

I keep trying to figure out a how to get jdwp to work with Embedded Java, using either a full jre or compact3 profile.  In both cases, it cannot find libjdwp.so.

According to [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-applications/headless.htm#CHDHCHCG), it should be supported, except in the minimal VM option of the JRE.  I am using the ARMv5 Linux (linux-arm-sflt) version, which I suspect might not include this anymore?  It was in the EJRE7 though, so I'm surprised it is missing now.  Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, with help from Jim Connors at Oracle.

You have to specify `--debug` (or `-g`) option to jrecreate.sh (or jrecreate.bat).

From the help:

> -g, --debug                Include Java level debugging support.